# add new item in table view : misunderstanding

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

There's something I don't understand with tableviews: how to add a new item in a table view.

Here's what I do: when i click on a button "+", the modal controller appears, we enter a new item, and the table view should be edited, with a new item at the bottom. In the rootViewController, I attach the tableWebsites mutable array to the modal viewcontroller, so we have a copy of the mutable array and we can add the new item at the end of this copy:

```
ModifViewController *addView = [[ModifViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModifViewController" bundle:nil];  
addView.tabWebSites = self.tabWebSites;
```

And finally, in the rootViewController, we say :

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

So we copied the mutable array in RootView... to be edited in ModifView... but how does the tableview know that the mutable array tableWebsites edited in ModifView...  is the one that should "fill" the table view? because we have a tableWebsites in RootView... and another tableWebsites in ModifView... in order to edit it. So i would think that : even if we say "reloadData", it will reload the same mutable array in the RootView.

Do you understand what i mean? i'm sorry if it's a mess, i have trouble to make myself clear ;) Thanks for your answer.

Paul

Comment: NO IT WOULD NOT RELOAD THE SAME MUTABLE ARRAY

Comment: @Legalos : thanks, but how do we specify that? nothing in the code actually says "fill the table view with the mutable array copy"... that's where i don't really understand it.

Comment: `addView.tabWebSites = self.tabWebSites;` copies the contents of tabWebsites of the current view to the tabWebsites of addView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView objects are actually asking their [data sources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for the values to display, as well as the number of sections, etc...Sending `reloadData` to the table view will make it re-asking these values.

So I think no matter with the array the data source is picking the values from, but these methods should **always** return the correct value.

Useful links :

[Table View programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

[UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITableView)

[UITableViewDataSource protocol reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource)

Comment: Thanks Vince, same thing as above actually :) -> how do we specify the mutable array? nothing in the code actually says "fill the table view with the mutable array copy"... that's where i don't really understand it.

Comment: The table view doesn't hold any data, instead it is asking its data source for a cell to display, at some section index and row index in the section.The data source is traditionally some view controller, which is the glue between the table view and some model object. So the table view will, first ask for the number of sections, then for each section ask the number of rows, and finally for each row ask for the cell to display. You can have a starter guide in my answer, i will edit.

Comment: Thanks Vince, well if it was only to fill a table view, it would be ok, because i understand what you mean, but i'm wondering how the new items are called, because actually, we have a self.tableWebsites count to know the number of cells, but we have another tableWebsites, in the other viewController...you know what i mean?

Comment: Not really but if you have two arrays and want to put some objects in it into the first, do it. As long as the data source is checking the right one, you are done.

Comment: So, when you say "checking the right one", we might have to specify (to the RootViewController) that the array to use in the table view is the one edited in ModifViewController : but in my code : there's nothing about it, it's like it's done automatically, but how? we first copied the array into an new array in ModifViewController, and then ... magic ... :) the data source knows that the right array is not self.myArray, but the one in ModifView... which is the controller that appears when we put on the "+" button. There's something i'm missing here...

Comment: no, no, there are few methods a table view data source **must** implement. For example that one : `-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;`. This method is supposed to return the number of sections the table view will display. In **this** (and other) method **you** choose which value to return, no matter how many arrays your controller manages.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's what we do in my code, but we precise "self.tabWebsites", which is the array from the start, with the very first data, not the one edited in the second controller, with the new data added, you know? i have added items in the array in the second controller, and i'm wondering how this array from the second controller can be linked to the table view, because in the RootViewController, i have my table view methods, the array from the start, and self.tabWebsites count for the rows... but nothing about the copy of the array, managed from the 2nd controller

Comment: ok I understand now.To do so, declare a weak (not retained) property in the 2nd VC pointing to the 1st, this way you add data directly by accessing the array property. Also if you accept my answer, you can click the checkmark on the left ;-)

Comment: someone told me the tabWesites is not "copied", but it is the same array, so if we edit this array in one or another VC, it doesn't matter, because it's the same. Do you confirm? he said we should have done : "copy" if we wanted to say that the array is copied...

Answer (score 0):

You are using numberOfRowsInSection method. It returns the number of rows.See that method Have you used [tabWebSites count] ? So after you add the value in array and when you again come back to Rootviewcontroller and execute [self.tableView reloadData]. It will execute all the TableView Methods again.